# update assembly version on git commit in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, c#

I am facing a nightmate of keeping track of not one, but 5 applications that regularly update and work together in tandem.

On each update, I must manually update AssemblyInfo.cs file with incremental version. Also, I store each version in git so I need to add a tag or commit message of current assembly version. This is super error prone, because I need to remember to modify assembly version on 2 location.

I'd like to connect this 2 operations together, so that on every commit or merge with production branch, assmebly version in AssemblyInfo.cs is updated/incremeneted and commit message/tag is set to current assembly version.

What is the best way to achieve this workflow? I am interested in both Visual Studio and Rider IDE.

Comment: You can do this with git hooks. It's been answered on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101473/change-version-file-automatically-on-commit-with-git

Comment: There should be a plugin for this but I can't find one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=git%20version&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=vs2019&sortBy=Relevance

Comment: This question was also cross posted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: For what it works, I've done something similar open source, MIT licensed https://github.com/smourier/UpdateAssemblyInfo (work on Windows but can be recompiled for linux with .NET core/5+), specially suited for git (pre) commit hook